# Can I give names to index values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have an array holding employee data:

[empID, empFName, empAge, empSalary, ...]

rather than each index being [0,1,...] can I instead give the index an identifier? I'm trying to create a loop where I store an array object [*employee*] inside of an array, with each index of the employee array holding one of the values above *empID, empFName, ...*,

What I'm trying to end up with is something like this:
[Employee1[101, Dave, 35, 50000], Employee2[...]...]

is this possible in Java?

Comment: Instead of using an array to store data, you should create a class. Then you can give names to the values.

Comment: Everything is possible in Java and this is a particularly basic use case, so yes. Just create integer constants and access your array indices with those constants.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Embrace what java is, which is a nominally typed system. Emphasis on **nominal**: Things are supposed to have names. Thus:

```
@Value
public class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    long salary;
}

List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(new Employee(101, "Dave", 35, 50000));
```

Some notes:

1. arrays are low level constructs you generally shouldn't be using unless you really know you need them, or its component type is primitive (`int[]` is much harder to avoid). Use Lists. These can shrink and grow and have funcioning implementations of equals and hashCode and the like.
2. You need to set up that class to have a constructor and such. If you're on java 14, you can use records; alternatively, you can use lombok's @Value, as in this example.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding you're essentially describing a 2D array. While that's possible and could get you to where you want to go, I think it'd be a lot easier and teach you a lot more if you created an employee object and stored them in an arraylist! Then, you'd access the info you want with arraylist.get(i).someEmployeeMethod() where someEmployeeMethod() could be something like getName() or getId(). If you don't know what an object is, you will definitely need to.